Issue integrating Firebase Realtime database with Dialogflow using inline editor
I am having issue ingrating my dialogflow intents with the firebase realtime database. I have a database in firebase that only has a single key/value pair that has the address. I have also initalized the dialogflow intent with the name getAddress. Can't seem to integrate the bot to firebase using fulfulment. Image of firebase database attached for reference.
Tell me what am I doing wrong.
Firebase file structure
'use strict';
 
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const {WebhookClient} = require('dialogflow-fulfillment');
const firebaseAdmin = require("firebase-admin");

process.env.DEBUG = 'dialogflow:debug'; // enables lib debugging statements

firebaseAdmin.initializeApp({
  credential: firebaseAdmin.credential.applicationDefault(),
  databaseURL: 'https://wax-bde2f.firebaseio.com/'
});
//const {Card, Suggestion} = require('dialogflow-fulfillment'); 
exports.dialogflowFirebaseFulfillment = functions.https.onRequest((request, response) => {
  const agent = new WebhookClient({ request, response });
  console.log('Dialogflow Request headers: ' + JSON.stringify(request.headers));
  console.log('Dialogflow Request body: ' + JSON.stringify(request.body));
 
  function welcome(agent) {
    agent.add(`Welcome to my agent!`);
  }

  function getFromFirebase(agent) {
    return firebaseAdmin.database().ref('address').once("value")
    .then((snapshot) => {
        if (snapshot.exists()) {
            agent.add(`Hey! The address is: ${snapshot.val()}`);
        } else {
            agent.add("Address not found in the database.");
        }
    })
    .catch((err) => {
        console.error("Error fetching data from Firebase:", err);
        agent.add("Sorry, there was an issue fetching the address.");
    });
  }
  let intentMap = new Map();
  intentMap.set('Default Welcome Intent', welcome);
  intentMap.set('getAddress', getFromFirebase);
  agent.handleRequest(intentMap);
});


"Can't seem to integrate" is hard to help with. Is there any error message? If not, did you already step a breakpoint on each line of code you shared and run it in the debugger?

Yes I debugged the code, I think there is some sort of issue with connection with the database as the function 'getFromFirebase' in the above code doesn't execute while getting response from "Intent Responses" for this function. welcome function is working fine.

Note that the welcome function is synchronous, but getFromFirebase executes an asynchronous call to the database. This probably explains the different in behavior, but I don't know enough about dialog flow agents to provide an answer how to handle this.

@murtaza can you provide more detail on the code, have you check the google logs explorer to see for errors or IAM issues?
And I think it would be better to use a Webhook just GOOGLE CLOUD FUNCTION it works best.
